# Ошибка при компиляции на XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, sqlite

Уже несколько дней не могу разобраться с проблемой, вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main()
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc;

    //rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

    return 0;
}
```

в этом случае компиляция проходит успешно, но при этом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main()
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc;

    rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);    // Возникает ошибка

    return 0;
}
```

выдает ошибку:

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
>       _main in main.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Не подключена библиотека?

Comment: Подключена, если не задейстую саму sqlite3 то норма, это видно в самом вопросе!

Comment: Там манглинг какой то, библиотека вероятно собрана так же? Проверьте, все же наличие именно библиотеки `.lib`, хеадер файл оно видит, отсюда нет ошибки при определении структуры, а вот с функциями проблема, не видит библиотеку, или та собрана с иными деклорациями имён.

Comment: @NewView у меня стандартный XCode со своим компилятором:

    'Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)'

Comment: в /usr/lib есть сама библиотека, libsqlite3.dylib

Comment: А в проекте указано, что с этой библиотекой нужно компоновать?

Comment: Это я о предположении того, что хедадер файл видит, и что сама библиотека на месте! Совсем не пойму в чем дело.

Comment: В том что библиотека не включена в проект. Или собрана как то по иному, в плане декларации имён, что маловероятно.

Comment: @АндрейСаламов То, что она видит хедер, еще не значит, что библиотека на месте. Вам нужно как-то в настройках проекта указать, что вы хотите использовать libsqlite3.dylib.

Comment: Что нибудь [в этом духе](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/xcode-link-static-lib.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В картинках примерно так можно добавить внешнюю библиотеку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще есть [хелп](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/) для этого изделия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло, спасибо что указали путь!)